# Compressing by counting repetitive elements (Haskell)

Tags: haskell, compression, run-length-encoding

I'm looking for a straight-forward combination of standard higher-order functions to compress a list by counting repetitive elements.
 For example the result for

`"abbccccb"`

would be :

```
 [(1, 'a'), (2, 'b'), (4, 'c'), (1, 'b')]
```

another example, the result for

```
(sort "abrakadabra")
```

would be:

```
[(5, 'a'), (2, 'b'), (1, 'd'), (1, 'k'), (2, 'r')]
```

Comment: You probably want to start with `Data.List.group` and continue from there.

Comment: That second example isn't like the first at all; the first is reversible, the second is just statistics.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I wrote a code that only makes use of elementary functions.

```
f :: Eq a => [a] -> [(Int, a)]
f [] = []
f (x:xs) = (1 + length (takeWhile (==x) xs), x) : f (dropWhile (==x) xs)
```

I hope this will help!.

Answer (score 10):

Start by using [`Data.List.group`](http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive/base/latest/doc/html/Data-List.html#v:group). This gives you a list of runs of equal elements, e.g.

```
> group "abbccccb"
["a","bb","cccc","b"]
```

Then, `map` over this list, taking the `head` and `length` of each run. This can be done elegantly with the [`&&&`](http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive/base/latest/doc/html/Control-Arrow.html#v:-38--38--38-) operator from `Control.Arrow`:

```
> map (length &&& head) . group $ "abbccccb"
[(1,'a'),(2,'b'),(4,'c'),(1,'b')]
```

Comment: A longer description of the above is the Run Length Encoding section from Real World Haskell: http://book.realworldhaskell.org/read/barcode-recognition.html#id631625

Answer (score 0):

You could also use `Control.Applicative` and the applicative functor instance of `(->) e`

```
map ((,) <$> length <*> head) . group
```

If you now wanted a triple with the `ord` value, it's really easy!

```
map ((,,) <$> length <*> head <*> ord . head) . group
```

However an anonymous function is probably clearer to the reader.

```
map (\xs -> (length xs, head xs, (ord . head) xs) . group
```